# Need advice on most effective List to use, and the best practice to generate unique ids to each member

Tags: java, list, file, collections, uniqueidentifier

So I've got this school project, and I would really like to approach it with the best practices.

I need to make a list of customers for an insurance company. Each of these shall have a unique customer number, generated in ascending order.

Every customer can have zero to many insurances, also stored in seperate lists for each customer. Adding of insurances will happen more often than adding of customers.

Every customer can also have any numbers of claims. Every claim also has a unique id number.

If a customer cancels all insurances. All data on this customer will remain as history.

All data need to be stored via one of the file classes in the Java Standard Library. Databases are not allowed.

Actions such as showing of statistics will also be available.

Users of the program will be employees, with rights to edit every data field.

**Questions:**

What Collection class would be the most effective one to use? LinkedList, ArrayList, Hashmap or any other?

What file class would be the best one for saving the lists? ObjectOutputStream?

What is the best method of generating new unique ids for both customers and claims? As private fields in the customer list class? Information on the next unique id has to be restored every time the program exits and restarts.

**Edit:**

Not looking for help with any code. Just advice on the most common classes to use in a scenario like this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you expecting us to do your homework? We can give advice, but you should put in some effort first.

Comment: I'm in the planning phase. So far I'm planning on going for an ArrayList. Generate the unique ids in a the customer list class, and saving the data using ObjectOutputStream. All I'm looking for is confirmation that this might be a good approach, or not. I have little to no experience on the best practises approaching these topics. Not looking for any more help. The rest is a learning process best achieved by my own hands.:)

Answer (score 0):

> What Collection class would be the most effective one to use?
>   LinkedList, ArrayList, Hashmap or any other?

Ans - LinkedList and ArrayList are types of List. HashMap is a type of Map. 
What implementation of List you want to use depends on your requirement. If you are going to perform insertions and removals of elements at different points of a List frequently, then LinkedList makes more sense. It is more efficient at, say for example, removing an element in the middle of the List. Otherwise prefer to use ArrayList.

> What is the best method of generating new unique ids for both
>   customers and claims? As private fields in the customer list class?
>   Information on the next unique id has to be restored every time the
>   program exits and restarts.

You may want to use a Singleton to generate IDs, and also persist them to a file.